# Copying SCP multiple files from remote server with wildcard argument in UNIX BASH

Tags: bash, unix, expect, scp

This Expect script is a part of my UNIX Bash script

```
expect -c " 
spawn scp yoko@sd.lindeneau.com:\"encryptor *.enc\" . 
expect password:  { send \"$PASS\r\"  }
expect 100%
sleep 1
exit
 "
```

I am trying to copy both 'encryptor' and '*.enc' with this one SCP command. Console tells me it cannot find ' *.enc" '

Comment: Related: [How to use wildcards (*) when copying with scp?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27419/how-to-use-wildcards-when-copying-with-scp)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for multiple files:

```
$ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:~/\{foo.txt,bar.txt\} .
```

I would guess in your case (untested)

```
scp yoko@sd.lindeneau.com:\\{encryptor, \*.enc\\} .
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it helps but I was looking for a similar objective.

Means: Copying some selected files based on their filenames / extensions but located in different subfolders (same level of subfolders).

this works e.g. copying .csv files from `Server:/CommonPath/SpecificPath/`

```
scp -r Server:/CommonPath/\*/\*csv YourRecordingLocation
```

I even tested more complex "perl like" regular expressions.

Not sure the `-r` option is still useful.

Comment: Sorry this interface removed the back slashes upfront wildcards. So it should be scp -r Server:/CommonPath/\\*/\\*csv YourRecordingLocation

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
set timeout 60; # 1 min 
spawn scp yoko@sd.lindeneau.com:{encryptor *.enc} .
expect \"password: $\"
send \"mypassword\r\"
expect eof
"
```

You can increase the `timeout` if your file copy takes more time to complete. I have used `expect eof` which will wait till the closure of the `scp` command. i.e. we are waiting for the End Of File (EOF) of the `scp` after sending the password.